# PHP parse error: syntax error on line 3... can it get much simpler?

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, include

I've been wrestling with this one for a bit;
I have small array I'd like to include:

mywords.php

```
<?php
$words = (
"test",
"one",
"two",
"three",
);
?>
```

and I of course include it correctly in the html:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('wordlist.php');
?>
```

but everytime I run it, no matter how large or small I make the array, I get the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/joedi3/faufum.com/wordlist.php on line 3
```

I've tried just about everything; here is what my phprc looks like:

```
log_errors = 1
error_log = /home/joedi3/php.log
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
max_execution_time = 500
max_input_time = 500
```

I doubt that even matters, but I figured I'd include it as its the only thing I can think of that could be messing it up.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: $words = array(..); or $words = [...];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Conde points out, or add `array` if your PHP version doesn't support the short syntax:

```
<?php
$words = array(
"test",
"one",
"two",
"three",
);
?>
```

Comment: This did it; my PHP version apparently doesn't support short syntax. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

Short array syntax uses brackets, not parenthesis:

```
<?php
$words = [
"test",
"one",
"two",
"three",
]
?>
```